# ScrollView does not work when adding TextViews programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I have a ScrollView and a LinearLayout within it defined in the xml file.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/planList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/planListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>
```

I add TextViews programmatically from the Activity.

```
    val textView = TextView(this)
    textView.text = text
    textView.setPadding(0, 8, 0, 8)
    textView.breakStrategy = LineBreaker.BREAK_STRATEGY_BALANCED
    binding.planListView.addView(textView)
```

It fills up the linearLayout. When the list exceeds the available size the scrollbar does not appear and no scrolling available at all.

What is wrong? How can I make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To make it works you need set layout properties properly.

```
texView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

binding.planListView.addView(textView)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have other elements above the ScrollView. Therefore I would like the ScrollView to use the available space. What shall I use instead of FILL_PARENT?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView`s scroll when their contents are larger than the `ScrollView` itself - it acts as a window, allowing you to move the contents back and forth so you can see different parts. If you set the height to `wrap_content`, you're ensuring the `ScrollView` will always be the same height as its contents - so it won't scroll, and it will potentially be partially off the screen (which is what's happening here - you can use the *Layout Inspector* to check, you'll see the view extending below the screen area).

You need to either give the `ScrollView` a fixed height, or otherwise constrain it so it won't extend off the screen when its contents grow too large. Generally, there'll be an area in your UI where you want the scrollable content window to appear - that area is your `ScrollView`. If its contents are too big to fit inside that area, it'll allow scrolling. That's about it!

Comment: I would choose 'otherwise constrain it so it won't extend off the screen when its contents grow too large'. What constrains shall I use?

Comment: @PeterHorvath use a `ConstraintLayout` and set the `ScrollView`'s bottom constraint to the bottom of `parent`, or the top of another view below. And set the top constraint too, so you're pinning the top and bottom of the `ScrollView` to the area you want it to occupy. Then make the `layout_height` *0dp* so it can resize to match your constraints. (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout)